# making top and bottom border curved in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend, bezier, figma

I am new to development. In figma design I have a div there where top border and bottom border are curved also there is arch in the center of top border of div. I have tried border radius but it does not give me the look like figma design.

Someone suggested me use svg path but it is very complex for me. Can someone suggest me better way of implementing it or svg code to implement this design.

Also I want this to be responsive for mobile screens and tab screens as well.

Figma design

[image]

I tried border radius but it does not give the look like figma.

Comment: SVG is probably the best way to achieve that look, but you’re right that it’s not really a beginner-level problem. You can use an SVG editor like [Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com/) to draw the curve as you want it to look, then you can take the code that it generates and add it to your HTML.

Also, Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, it's not a coding service. Don't expect anyone here to write code for you.

Comment: What do you want it to look like on differently dimensioned elements, foe example if the viewport aspect ratio changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.ellipse{ 
     height:400px;
     background:#f66;
     clip-path: ellipse(59% 50%);
     margin-top: 100px;
}
.arch { 
  height: 500px;
  background: #f66;
  margin-top: -500px;
}
.a1{ 
  clip-path: ellipse(45% 31%);
}
.a2{ 
  clip-path: ellipse(45% 32%);
}
.a3{ 
  clip-path: ellipse(45% 33%);
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipse">
</div>
<div class="arch a1">
</div>
<div class="arch a2">
</div>
<div class="arch a3">
</div>
```

Comment: it worked very well. But now only the issue is of little arch at the center of upper border as you can see in the design

Answer (score 1):

You can try clip-path like that:

```
clip-path: ellipse(200px 500px at 50% 50%);
```

Comment: If you're giving a pure CSS answer, at the very least include a runnable snippet that shows it off, and explain why you you're recommending it.